# is it possible to set up sugarcrm so that during SSO, language for the application is also selected

Tags: sugarcrm

I have created custom SSO for sugarcrm. Now, users can login the system with another system login credentials.
The problem is I do not know to select language in 'Login Page' so that selected language is applied to user's session in crm. Do I need to send some parameters to crm in login page? Please, help me

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. I put following code right after session start code:

```
    $_SESSION['authenticated_user_language']='en_us';
```

It worked for me.